# Custom Assembly in SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

I created a custom assembly that I'm trying to run in my SSRS 2008 project.  This is a simple static method in a class:

```
namespace Utilties
{
    public class Expressions
    {
        public static string SayHello()
{
    return "Hello Test!";
}
    }
}
```

The project compiles into an assembly.  Then I go to Report > Properties and add the assembly there and in the following location:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
```

My understanding is that by default, the assembly already has execute permissions as I do not intend on adding Code support using CAS.

I inserted a textbox in my report with the expression:

```
=Utilities.Expressions.SayHello()
```

But when I build, I get an error:

> [rsCompilerErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun
>   ‘Textbox16.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30451]
>   Name 'Utilities' is not declared.

Is there an additional step I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind the question.  The problem was that I mispelled the namespace.  Once I corrected the issue, the problem went away and everything worked the way it should.